# Configure a Virtual Ethernet Interface with Static IP - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: network-manager, ethernet

I am trying to set up a virtual Ethernet interface on my Ubuntu 22.04 system and have encountered some difficulties.

I would like to create a virtual interface named test1 with a specific static IP address. This interface should auto-start on system boot.

Here's what I am aiming for:

```
Interface Name: test1
IP Address: 172.17.0.1/16
Auto-start on boot
```

There is documentation to assign an ip to a physical interface with nmcli. But nothing to assign an IP to a virtual interface.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to configure this virtual Ethernet interface in Ubuntu 22.04 using NetworkManager.

Thank you in advance for your help!

---

### Edit 1

What I need is access my ngnix server from 172.17.0.1 on my computer.

Because I can't add this ip to a physical card, I need to create a virtual interface to which I can assign this ip.

I know that I can use 127.0.0.1, but that's not what I want.

Comment: What do you mean by "virtual interface"? Where does it come from? What do you want to attach it to? Please elaborate a bit more on your question.

Comment: Hello @zwets, I have edited my quesion, I hope that it's clear enough, if not, please tell me what information you need to help me

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you mean by a "virtual ethernet interface". What is it?